# sort array list of special strings, by date

Tags: java, arraylist, sorting

I have an arrayList.

This is an arrayList of strings. The string contains a `"Date.toString"` in format of `"January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT"` + task name.

For example:

```
"January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT clean the house".
```

I want to sort this arrayList by dates.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 5):

You *could* write a comparator that parses the dates and sorts them using `date.compareTo(otherDate)`, but I'd suggest you store `dates` instead of `Strings` in the first place, making sorting much easier (Date implements `Comparable<Date>`.

(If your input format is `String`, then convert the `Strings` at the time you add them to the list)

Comment: +1, though I'd recommend to store the Date *in addition to* the String, rather than "instead of".

Comment: @Cperkins Then you should upvote Christoffer Hammarström's answer :-)

Answer (score 4):

For each `String`, convert it to a `Date`, possibly using a `SimpleDateFormat`, and put them all in a `TreeMap<Date,String>`, which will sort them for you.

**Edit**: And as @Sean Patrick Floyd suggested, do it on input.

Comment: I like the idea, it's a best of both worlds solution (1+)

Answer (score 2):

I would convert this array list first to something like

```
public class Event {
    private Date date;
    private String description;
    ...
}
```

After that, create a comparator to compare 2 events like this:

```
public class EventComparator implements Comparator<Event>{
    public int compare(Event e1, Event e2) {
        return e1.getDate().compareTo(e2.getDate());
    }
}
```

This will save you tons of performance compared with (pardon me) parsing each string for each comparison.

Comment: +1 for another valid solution, although I'd rather go with mine or Christoffer's

Answer (score 1):

Write a comparator in which, convert the strings to dates for comparison. `Collections.sort(List, Comparator);` does the job after that.

Comment: Beware of complexity: this means parsing each date String once per comparison

Answer (score 0):

Write your own comparator. Then use `Collections.sort(arrayList, myComparator);`

```
Comparator<String> myComparator = new Comparator<String>() {

 int compareTo(String string1, String string2) {
     ......
 }

 boolean equals(String str1) {
    ......
 }

}
```

Comment: Beware of complexity: this means parsing each date String once per comparison

Answer (score 0):

Convert the array into a list of dates and then sort them:

```
List<Date> dates = new ArrayList<Date>();
for(String s : dateStringArray){
  // split the date and task name
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\w+ \\d{1,2}, \\d{4}, \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2} \\w{3})(.*)");
  Matcher matcher = p.matcher(s);
  String taskname = "";
  String datestring = "";
  if (matcher.find()) {
    datestring = matcher.group(1);
    taskname = matcher.group(2);
  }
  // parse the date
  Date d = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy, HH:mm:ss z", 
               Locale.ENGLISH).parse(datestring);
  dates.add(d);
}
// sort the dates
Collections.sort(dates);
```

If you want to keep the task names, you will have to make own objects that have the date and the task as fields and are comparable by the dates.