# Trouble Sorting an ArrayList of Strings

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [sort array list of special strings, by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6059509/sort-array-list-of-special-strings-by-date)

I have an ArrayList of Strings that read in from a file and the first part of each string is a date ex: 12/01/2012. When I use Collections.sort(); it sorts it fine within the year from oldest to newest, but when it gets to 01/01/2013 it throws that up on the top of the list with the oldest. How can I get it to use the year as part of the sort? I tried using Date, but it did the same. Each string has a lot of info I would like to keep in it and just sort it by the beginning. I see no need to post code since it's working and all I'm having trouble with is just sorting. I've searched on here for awhile and tried a few different sorting options to no avail. So I must be confused or forgetting something. If anyone has any ideas how to sort Strings with dates in the beginning please help! Thanks!

example string: "12/01/2012   34023843   Item Number"

Comment: "I see no need to post code since it's working and all I'm having trouble with is just sorting" <-- you don't see the need, SO sees the need.

Comment: What do you mean by: `I tried using Date, but it did the same.`

Comment: We don't want to see all your code - but we do want to see your sorting code.  Please make a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/): just have some hard coded example strings in a list, and show us what you're doing to sort it ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a custom comparator. Comparing strings in natural order (ie, using the fact that `String` implements `Comparable<String>`) will give the result you see, since `0` is lower than `1`, so this is expected.

Here is an example class which can do what you want, but note that it assumes all dates are correctly formatted (the `parse()` method of `DateFormat` throws an unchecked `IllegalArgumentException` if the date is incorrect):

```
public final class MyComparator
    implements Comparator<String>
{
    // Date parsing
    // Note: SimpleDateFormat is not thread-safe, if possible use Joda Time instead
    private static final DateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/YYYY");

    private static final Comparator<String> INSTANCE = new MyComparator();

    private MyComparator()
    {
    }

    public static Comparator<String> getInstance()
    {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2)
    {
        // Grab dates
        String s1 = o1.subString(0, 10);
        Date d1 = fmt.parse(s1);
        String s2 = o2.subString(0, 10);
        Date d2 = fmt.parse(s2);

        // Date implements Comparable<Date>, so we can use that...
        int ret = d1.compareTo(d2);

        // If dates are equal, compare the rest of the strings instead.
        return ret != 0 ? ret : o1.subString(10).compareTo(o2.subString(10));
    }
}
```

You can then use `Collections.sort(theArray, MyComparator.getInstance());`

Answer (score 1):

If the string is always the same format, you can implement a custom [comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) and use Collections.sort(list, comparator)
This comparator will firstly check for years, then month, then day.

Or, (the best solution ahma), you could redesign to have a list of object with multiple fields (and a date), and implement a comparator using the date. It's never save to work directly with strings (for exemple here with a comparator on strings, you will not be able to work with other date format)

Comment: I read that on Oracle's site earlier and I was having trouble understanding how to implement it. Thanks for the suggestion though. I guess I'll keep looking into this approach. Do you have any examples of how using a comparator might look?

Comment: @user1941665 see my answer, there is a full example

Answer (score 1):

You are currently sorting using String ordering.  Which means "01/01/2013" sorts before "12/31/2012" since "0" is smaller than "1".

You can use a [custom comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) to use different logic.  Inside your comparator, you would:

1. Split the String to just get the date
2. Use SimpleDateFormat to turn field 0 into a date
3. Then call compare to on your two dates

Comment: I did attempt to do that. That's what I meant by "I tried using date" but, I don't understand how comparing two dates will help me sort a whole list of dates. Am I thinking about that part wrong?

Comment: This is where showing some code would have helped.  Your custom comparator is defining order for you.  So you can say "return date1.compareTo(date2).  The comparator is passed to sort() and calls it for the proper order/elements on the list.

Comment: "Am I thinking about that part wrong?" - Frankly, yes.  All  sort algorithms that are applicable to this problem work by comparing pairs of elements.  In your case, comparing pairs using the "natural order" of strings is giving you the wrong answer.  You have to extract and parse the dates and compare those ...

Answer (score 0):

@fge's answer works, but the comparator has to split and convert the strings multiple times.  In fact, for a typical sort algorithm this needs to be done `O(NlogN)` times, where `N` is the length of the list.  For a large list, the `logN` term will be significant.

My suggestion is to create a custom `Line` class to represent the lines from the file.  Have the constructor parse the string representing line into components, parse the date component and hold all relevant components in private fields.  Have the custom class implement `Comparable<Line>`, and implement the `compareTo(Line)` method to compare the lines by date.

Then represent the file contents as an `ArrayList<Line>` rather than `ArrayList<String>`.

(The chances are that you would need to parse the lines anyway ... after they have been sorted.  So this approach is simply doing the parsing before the sorting, and only doing it once.  FWIW, the answers to "duplicate" question cover this too: [sort array list of special strings, by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6059509/sort-array-list-of-special-strings-by-date))